# How to display that grey opacity/filter on hover for nav menu

Tags: html, css

I have looked at this website and I like the way they set their nav menu on hover: https://www.cleverbirds.com/

I did an inspect and took the element I believe that does this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    
#site-header:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) !important;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.1s!important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.1s!important;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.1s!important;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.1s!important;
}

}
```

However, I can't get that grey opacity/filter on the hover. It just seems completely transparent . How can I get it to show that grey background/filter on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this site, and even if you disable these rules in real time, the opacity on hover will still work.

Just use rule `background: rgba(0,0,0,.5)` for **hover**. Also, I wrapped the **hover** in the **media request** you specified. Expand to full screen and test.

I gave you a small example. If you have any questions, please let me know.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 5000px;
  background-color: green;
}

.menu {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.1s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.1s;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  .menu:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);  
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```